expo router tab icon that is a route only (not a screen)
I have 2 groups of screens (home) and (profile)
(home)
  _layout.tsx
  index.tsx
  chat.tsx
  camera.tsx
  next.tsx (don't want this screen)
(profile)
  _layout.tsx
  profile.tsx
  hidden.tsx
  ...

In (home)/_layout.tsx is it possible to define a tab icon that is not a screen but only navigates to /profile?  There is an href option but that still requires a screen name and will put the screen on the stack.  I've created a "screen" (home)/next.tsx which uses a router redirect to /profile.  This kinda works but I feel like this navigation pattern can be done a better way.
 return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? "light"].tint,
        headerShown: useClientOnlyValue(false, true),
      }}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: "Stuff",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="gift" color={color} />,
          headerRight: () => (
            <Link href="/modal" asChild>
              <Pressable>
                {({ pressed }) => (
                  <FontAwesome
                    name="info-circle"
                    size={25}
                    color={Colors[colorScheme ?? "light"].text}
                    style={{ marginRight: 15, opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1 }}
                  />
                )}
              </Pressable>
            </Link>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="chat"
        options={{
          title: "Chat",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="wechat" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="camera"
        options={{
          title: "New",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <TabBarIcon name="plus-circle" color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tabs.Screen
        name="next"
        options={{
          title: "Profile",
          href: "/profile",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="user" color={color} />,
        }}
      />

      <Tabs.Screen
        name="auth"
        options={{
          href: null,
        }}
      />

      <Tabs.Screen
        name="login"
        options={{
          href: null,
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}


In next.tsx currently I'm redirecting to /profile.
import { Redirect, router } from "expo-router";

export default function Page() {
  router.dismiss();
  return <Redirect href="/profile" />;
}

